# Validating a file is what it claims to be by it's file extension

Tags: cocoa, file-extension, nsfilemanager

Is there a way to validate a file is what it claims to be according to it's file extension?

I have a large number of files that my application copies to a remote server. Before doing each file copy I would like to validate that the file is in fact what the file extension claims it to be.

Right now the user selects the files and/or directories of files using `NSOpenPanel`. Once I have an array of files I can validate each one physically exists before the copy commences. I have the validation that the source directory is writable working fine and a copy using `FSCopyObjectAsync` with all the file cancellation in place is also working fine.

The last piece is this validation check. My users are limited in what they can upload, but the filter is done using the file extension. A malicious user could, for example, take a word document file (.doc by file extension) and change it to a .png in order for it to pass the initial open dialog box validation.

This is a rather simplistic example. The files are utilized by the server and I just want to make sure that files that won't work don't get uploaded.

I looked at `NSFileManager` `attributeOfItems:atPath:`, but it doesn't seem to offer any information for the real file type. The file type only returns that of a directory, symbolic link etc.

I would rather not attempt to open and load every file to validate, just read the file header and check it conforms to whatever file type spec it needs to.

This is not an iOS app.

Any and all help or pointers in the right direction much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, no. The file system only knows a few very limited things about a file. There can be further metadata associated, but in many cases there won't be -- and in any case, metadata can lie. If you want to be certain that a file really contains what it claims, you need to open it and look.

Depending on the file type and level of trust, you may not have to look at the whole thing. For example, the file may have a magic number in its first bytes, or there may be other header info that's enough to convince you. But their presence does not guarantee that the file will "work".

Comment: Then opening the header of the file it is. :-( But at least it's a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could use libmagic or [MagicKit](https://github.com/aidansteele/MagicKit/), an Objective-C wrapper around libmagic. MagicKit can return the UTI or the MIME type of a given file.

Comment: Thanks Bavarious, as much as this might work, there are commercial shipping implications we have of using third party software. So this would be a non-starter (although it might come in hand for some future project)

Comment: Bavarious - I take that back. MagicKit is MIT licensed so it moght work. Will check it out and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running `/usr/bin/file --mime` on it to get a MIME type.

Comment: Kevin - worth a try but no luck. I renamed a jpg to a png and --mime on it reports it now as a png instead of a jpg. Good idea though.